# GIT merge attempted but says "up to date"

Tags: git, merge

I've looked at the other links regarding this question and they don't seem to answer what my problem is.

We completely refactored our application. During refactoring a small team (including myself) used a branch called `refactor` to keep our work under source control. When we were all done and were ready to replace the old application with the refactored application I had to create 4 branches inside of GIT:

- `development`
- `qa`
- `staging`
- `master`

I accomplished this as follows:

1. Using my copy of `refactor` I went to bash and issued the command `git checkout -b development`
2. I pushed the `development` branch to the server
3. I followed steps 1 and 2 for `qa`, `staging` and `master`

We have now started a sprint. All developers have cloned `development` and then issued the bash command `git checkout -b <featurename>` and done their work in there. When completed they merge their work back to `development` using the commands:

- `git checkout development`
- `git merge --no-ff <featurename>`
- `git push origin development`

Later I go in myself and merge `development` to `qa` by doing the following.

On my local copy of `qa` I completed the following steps:

1. `git pull`
2. `git mrege --no-ff origin/development`
3. I then `commit` and `push` to `qa`

This worked for two of the developers. Just yesterday a developer merged his feature branch into `development` and asked me to do the merge of `development` to `qa`. I can see in the logs that the feature is in `development` and NOT in `qa`. When on `qa` I issue the command `git pull` and it says everything is up to date. Then I do `git merge--no-ff origin/development` it says "Already up to date".

I am unable to merge `development` to `qa`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to:

```
$ git fetch
```

My guess is that `git pull` is only fetching the current branch (`qa`). That means that the tracking branch `origin/development` is not getting updated. To check this is true, run the command (before and after `git fetch`):

```
$ git log qa..origin/development
```

This will return empty if `qa` and `origin/development` are exactly the same.

Comment: I ran the command and it was indeed empty so I did git fetch and that enabled me to do the merge. Thanks!